# Window added property return undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to load and use right after an external script in vanilla JS

```
const script = document.createElement('script');                                                                        
script.type = 'text/javascript';                                                                                        
script.src = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js';                                                                 
document.querySelector('footer').after(script);                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
console.log(window); // return following
/*
Window
    [...]
​
    "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf": Object { addLinkAttributes: Getter, getFilenameFromUrl: Getter, LinkTarget: Getter, … }
​
    pdfjsLib: Object { addLinkAttributes: Getter, getFilenameFromUrl: Getter, LinkTarget: Getter, … }
*/
    
console.log(window["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"]); // return undefined                     
console.log(window.[pdfjsLib]); // return undefined
console.log(window.pdfjsLib); // return undefined
```

How can I get this window object or why I can't ?

Comment: That's because all of your code is executed as-is and does not wait for the PDF.js script to be loaded.

Comment: The keys `pdfjs-dist/build/pdf` and `pdfjsLib` have not been defined, that's why you are getting undefined. If they are defined in pdf.js, that's another story.

Comment: where are you assigning the value `pdfjs-dist/build/pdf` to the window ?

Comment: The console.log entry is probably not evaluated immediately this is why you see `pdfjsLib` as being defined.

Comment: Your comments sum up @tevemadar answser, thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comments point out, it's the browser tricking you: `console.log(someobject)` often creates some kind of "active" log, which shows the current status of an object when you are looking at it in the console and not the status at the point of printing the log.

If the object is simple, you may see the original value, like here:

```js
let obj={a:0};
console.log(obj);
obj.a=1;
console.log(obj);
```

Which looks nice here, and if you open the console of your browser, you will see something what looks okay:

> ```
> >{a: 0}
> >{a: 1}
> ```

However if you "open" the first triangle, it becomes to something like

> ```
> .{a: 0}
>    a: 1
>   >__proto__: Object
> ```

So the "one-liner" shows the original state, but the in-depth view shows the current state. And if an object is "long", you simply won't get to see much of the original state in the one-liner, you can only see only the current state (after you open the triangle):

```js
let obj={q:0,w:0,e:0,r:0,t:0,y:0,u:0,i:0,o:0,p:0,s:0,d:0,f:0,g:0,h:0,j:0,k:0,l:0,z:0,x:0,c:0,v:0,b:0,n:0,m:0}
console.log(Object.keys(obj).length);
console.log(obj);
obj.a=1;
console.log(Object.keys(obj).length);
console.log(obj);
```

Here the object initially has no `a` field, see that `Object.keys(obj).length` first produces 25, and it becomes 26 for the second time only. But you couldn't tell that from looking at the one-liners, which show 4-5-6 fields only, then `...`, and if you look at the details, `a:0` will be present in the first log too. (Again, in the console of your browser).

And this is what happens with the script too, if you wait for the script to actually load (an `onload` handler has been added), `window` suddenly has 2 new fields, the ones you wanted to use:

```js
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload=function(){
  console.log("Yep");
  console.log(Object.keys(window).length);
  console.log(typeof window["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"]);
  console.log(typeof window.pdfjsLib);
};
script.src = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js';
document.querySelector('#footer').after(script);console.log("Nope");
console.log(Object.keys(window).length);
console.log(window["pdfjs-dist/build/pdf"]);
console.log(window.pdfjsLib);
```

```html
<div id="footer"></div>
```